# Oracle to Parquet decimals in Azure Data Factory loses all precision and scale

Tags: oracle, azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory, databricks

I'm trying to extract data using Azure Data Factory from Oracle to Parquet in ADLS. The problem I have is: whatever I try, the datatype decimal(p,s) in Oracle will always change to decimal(38,18) in my parquet file.

I've tried dynamically mapping the column in the mapping menu in Azure Data Factory:

[image]

However, my datatype in the parquet file will still be 38,18:

[image]

I've tried with an MSSQL Server as source and that works fine.

This is what my Mapping looks like in ADF (but i've tried different options/values):

```
 "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "mappings": [
                        {
                            "source": {
                                "name": "COLUMN",
                                "type": "Decimal",
                                "physicalType": "decimal",
                                "scale": 1,
                                "precision": 4
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "name": "COLUMN",
                                "type": "Decimal",
                                "physicalType": "DECIMAL",
                                "scale": 1,
                                "precision": 4
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "typeConversion": true,
                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                        "allowDataTruncation": false,
                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                    }
                }
```

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem in reading data from oracle. Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the issue still persists. We decided to extract oracle using Databricks directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is that as performant as data factory?

Comment: @ARCrow for large datasets definitely not, since it doesnt scale as well as it isn't using integration runtimes, but for small batches it does the job

Comment: Thanks man. Appreciate you help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the decimal scale and precision in the `Derived column` transformation in Azure Data Factory `dataflow` activity.

In my example, I am adding an expression to get precision **7** and scale **1** of column **salary**.

[image]

**Sink preview:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I've also come around this workaround but unfortunately is not an option since DataFlows do not have oracle as an option for a source. I can do preprocessing ofcourse, and use Data Flows later, but it would be a real hassle to add derived columns for every column. And since we're already using databricks, we're probably going to do typecasting there. I've got in touch with Microsoft, and the ADF team is going to look into the issue.

Comment: Did you get any updates around the issue from Microsoft @JVGBI ??

Comment: @JavierdelaIglesia I have, they have replied that there is currently no fix for this :(.